# how to a link in Admin black toolbar

Tags: 8, navigation

[image]

I created a custom module and how to add a link along with icon. Basically, I want to add notification icon

```
backlinks_notifications.index:
  title: 'Notifications'
  parent: system.admin_config_ui (whats the name of that blad navigation bar on top.)
  description: 'Notificationsx'
  url: internal:/home
```

FYI : Its Admin theme.

Comment: Take a look at the module [Toolbar Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/toolbar_menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   /**
    * Implements hook_toolbar().
    */
    function backlinks_notifications_toolbar() {
        $items = [];
        $items['toolbar_menu_backlinks_notifications'] = [
            '#type' => 'toolbar_item',
            'tab' => [
                '#type' => 'link',
                '#title' => 'Notifications',
                '#url' =>  Url::fromRoute('<front>'),
                '#options' => [
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'title' => t('Backlinks Notification'),
                        'class' => array(
                        'toolbar-item',
                        'toolbar-icon',
                        'toolbar-icon-backlinks-notifications',
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            ],
            '#weight' => 999,
            '#attached' => array(
                'library' => array(
                    'backlinks_notifications/backlinks_notifications',
                ),
            ),
        ];
        return $items;
    }
```

Hook available at 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21toolbar%21toolbar.api.php/function/hook_toolbar/8.2.x